# How to know that a command was executed and finished to execute another one(ssh - php )

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh, cmd

I'm creating a button on my web page.I want that when someone presses this button an execution of a process of Linux commands on my first server (like "cd file" "./file_to_execute"..) when these commandes are done and finished i want to connect on another server by ssh and to execute another commands. 
the probleme is how can i know that the commands before are already finished to proceed to the second part which is to connect on another server .
to resume :
first step connect on the first server , execute some commands 
=> when these commands are done ( the part i dont know how to do it )
second step : to connect on another server and execute some others commands.
I'm searching for a way that will allows me to add some pop up to inform the user of my web page that he finished the first step and he started the second.

```js
<?php
$hostname = '192.177.0.252';  
$username = 'pepe';
$password = '*****';  
$commande = 'cd file && ./file_one.sh';    

if (false === $connection_first = ssh2_connect($hostname, 22)) {
  echo 'failed<br />';
  exit(); 
  }
else {
  echo 'Connected<br />';
  }
 
if (false === ssh2_auth_password($connection_first, $username, $password)) {
  echo 'failed<br />';
  exit(); 
  }
else {
  echo 'done !<br />';
  }
 
if (false === $stream = ssh2_exec($connection_first, $commande)) {
  echo "error<br />";
  }
?>
```

Thanks

PS: sorry for my English, I'm from Barcelone

Answer (score 0):

To handle events where an exception occurs i would recommend using a try/catch statement, like the one below:

```
 try {
     echo inverse(5) . "\n";
     echo inverse(0) . "\n";
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }
```

When you're trying to handle events and need to know when they finish, there are a few ways to achieve this. You can either set a boolean to true after the command has been executed (like what you are already doing). OR you can return output from the command by printing the output to a txt file and then echoing out the returns of this file. See code below:

```
exec ('/usr/bin/flush-cache-mage > /tmp/.tmp-mxadmin');
$out =  nl2br(file_get_contents('/tmp/.tmp-mxadmin'));
echo $out;
```

At this point you can create conditions based off of what is returned in the `$out` variable.